# Como saber que JQuery esta funcionando o en que archivo se encuentra

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Estoy intentando poner un **ScrollTo** pero no se esta aplicando porque esta chocando con otro **JQuery** que tiene un *botón flotante* que al hacerle *click*  dirige al inicio de la página, entonces quiero encontrar el JQuery que tenía la plantilla por *default* pero no logro saber donde esta.
Este es el *JQuery* que quiero poner y esta chocando con otro y digo esta chocando porque si esta cargando el JQuery.

**ScrollTo:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate( {
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-40
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    } );
  } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul role="tablist">
  <li class="active" id="p1"><a href="#pane1" role="tab">Section 1</a></li>
  <li id="p2"><a href="#pane2" role="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  <li id="p3"><a href="#pane3" role="tab">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="pane1">Primera parte</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="pane2">Segunda parte</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="pane3">Tercera parte</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

**Botón que sube de la plantilla:**

```html
<a href="#" class="scrollup">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar que una función se ejecuta puedes poner dentro de ella un `console.log('ejecuta');` o `alert('ejecuta');` por ejemplo, con el `console.log` lo veras en la consola del inspector de elementos, con el `alert` te aparecerá un mensaje en la página, así puedes ver de dónde viene el problema.

Si una vez has probado esto no encuentras solución al problema, dímelo y te ayudo.

Suerte.

Comment: Si eso si lo se pero yo me referia a si mientras debugeo el codigo se podra saber a que funcion de del archivo .js entra

Comment: Si, simplemente poniendo diferentes console.log(...) dentro de cada función, con nombres distintos, puedes ver a medida que avanzan las funciones, por que parte va. Por ejemplo, si tienes una función, dentro de una función y dentro, otra, pones 3 console.log() distintos y te aparecerán por orden de ejecución.